# WorkFusion RPA Express does not Start on System Restart

Tags: automation, rpa, workfusion

I have installed **Workfusion RPA Express** for exploring and evaluation. The software is working perfectly fine since I installed it. Once the system restarts, the software won't start with the below welcome screen.

[image: Screenshot]

I tried leaving the system overnight stuck with this screen but next day, I got to see the same screen. I had to uninstall and install the software to make it work again at the next restart. Is this a bug ?

Request you to please help me with this issue as I have to uninstall and install the software at every restart. Please let me know if additional details are required, I would be more than glad to help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is outside the scope of Stack Overflow (as defined in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)).

Comment: @esqew As mentioned in the help center the question directly involves software tool (Workfusion RPA Express) used primarily for programming (in this case Robotic Process Automation) so I am not sure if it is an off-topic question. Additionally, I have added the answer which I have received from Workfusion Service Desk.

Comment: Fair - I've rescinded my close vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have got an reply from **Workfusion Service Desk** for this issue. I have followed the steps mentioned by them in the email which has resolved this issue.

> Some of RPA Express files are locked by other processes. Below are the steps to resolve it:
>
> 1. Exit from RPA Express using the tray icon or, if no icon is shown in the tray, kill the RPA Express processes with Task Manager as described in [RPA Express does not respond issue](https://kb.workfusion.com/display/RPAe/Troubleshooting#expand-RPAExpressdoesnotrespond)
> 2. Delete the following files:
>
>    1. RPA Express log files:
>
>       1. C:\RPAExpress\RPA\wfagent\logs-rpax\status-agent-process.log
>       2. C:\RPAExpress\RPA\wfagent\logs-rpax\status-agent-error.log
>       3. C:\RPAExpress\RPA\wfagent\logs-rpax\status-agent.log
>       4. C:\RPAExpress\RPA\wfagent\logs-rpax\metrics.log
>    2. Eclipse Manager file:
>
>       1. C:\RPAExpress\Recorder\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi.manager.fileTableLock
>    3. Restart RPA Express
>
> **Note**: Location of the files depends on the path, where you have installed RPA Express.